# Kendo UI Grid - Row filter debounce inputs

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using a kendo grid in the same way as the following demo: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/filter-row

Is there anyway of adding a debounce time to the string filter inputs so the filter is applied "as the user types"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this by adding the code in the column you want to filter while typing:

```
 filterable: {
                            cell: {
                                operator: "contains",
                                template: function (args) {
                                   args.element.css("width", "90%").addClass("k-textbox").keydown(function(e){
                                     setTimeout(function(){
                                                          $(e.target).trigger("change");
                                                         });
                                   });
                                }

                            }
                        }
```

I've made an example here:

http://dojo.telerik.com/ApukU